# Vectorial comparison with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new with django (as well as django rest framework) and I am a little bit lost.
I manage to follow the tutorial and I have my REST API server running. I can post data, get them from my database, everything is working fine but I have problems understanding how to make custom functions. I clearly have some notions missing.

I would like to POST a vector ([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0] for example) as a JSON and I would like my server to get all vectors from my database, compare them and then returns me a similarity score.

I don't even know how to post a simple number, multiply it by 2 and then return the result as a JSON. Does someone has a good tutorial for that or could explain me how I can achieve such a simple thing? I will then figure out by myself my vector comparison :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this without actually testing the code, so it may have a couple of typos or issues but it should help you get started. It shows how to make a custom API. In this case, I am taking a vector and multiplying each item by two and returning that:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    vector = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=100)
    )


class TestViewSet(APIView):

    #permission_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            vector = serializer.data.get('vector')

            new_vector = []
            for item in vector:
                new_vector.append(item*2)

            new_data = {
                'vector': new_vector
            }

            return Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hope it puts you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks, I made some modifications but it helped me understand some points I was missing :)